# What does compiling prevent?

Tags: ruby, bytecode

RubyVM can compile Ruby code to byte code, and then execute it directly. e.g.,

**COMPILE.rb**

```
File.write(ARGV[1],RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file(ARGV[0]).to_binary)
```

**EXECUTE.rb**

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary(File.read(ARGV[0]).force_encoding(Encoding::ISO_8859_1)).eval
```

**Test.bat**

```
ruby COMPILE.rb test.rb test.rbx
ruby EXECUTE.rb test.rbx
```

The ruby code of `test.rb` itself actually executes. Are there any significant disadvantages here? A friend suggested that one might want to be careful as it may not end up running on other Operating Systems. However I'd expect that it would work on all Operating Systems, e.g. like Java bytecode, which can run on all operating systems as they are executed by the JVM.

Are there any obvious downsides that come with compiling Ruby to byte code, (except of course readability)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standardized byte code format for Ruby. Therefore, whatever you have there, it is *not* "Ruby byte code", it is byte code for *one* version of *one* implementation of Ruby.

In your particular case, it is byte code for YARV. It will not work on MRuby, JRuby, Rubinius, Opal, MagLev, IronRuby, Topaz, MRI, or any other Ruby implementation.

Also, YARV does not guarantee forwards or backwards compatibility for its byte code, so there is no guarantee it will work on newer or older versions of YARV. [The documentation says](http://ruby-doc.org/core/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html):

> The instruction sequence results will almost certainly change as Ruby changes

Likewise, YARV does not guarantee byte code portability, so there is no guarantee it will work on a different operating system, different CPU, or different platform, even using the same version of YARV.

Lastly, YARV's byte code is *unsafe*, and there is no verifier. YARV will happily execute any unsafe byte code without checking, and you can construct byte code that leaves the VM in an unsafe state. Therefore, you should *never ever* do this with byte code you haven't created yourself and that is fully under your own control. [The documentation says](http://ruby-doc.org/core/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-c-load_from_binary):

> This loader does not have a verifier, so that loading broken/modified binary causes critical problem.
>
> You should not load binary data provided by others. You should use binary data translated by yourself.

Note that with regards to your specific question:

> Are there any obvious downsides that come with compiling Ruby to byte code, (except of course readability)?

You seem to be under the false impression that you actively need to do something special in order to compile Ruby to byte code. That is not necessarily true.

If you use YARV, Rubinius, MRuby, MagLev, or Topaz, then your Ruby code is *always* compiled to byte code, without you having to do anything. With IronRuby and JRuby, it may or may not be compiled to byte code, depending on whether the code is "hot" enough.

Also, with MagLev, your byte code will be compiled to native code if it is "hot" enough, with Rubinius and YARV, it *might* get compiled to native code depending on the version, and with IronRuby and JRuby, the CIL / JVM byte code might get compiled to native code depending on the CLI VES / JVM implementation.

Comment: Good answer +1.  I have never personally messed with compiling Ruby to byte code, though I have seen functions to do so and was curious as OP is. I always felt it was simply Ruby trying to implement some Python-esque features, but saw that it was far too immature to be put to practical use. Maybe by Ruby 5.0 they will have it implemented, but I doubt it even then, and is it really even necessary? If something is so performance critical that the marginal improvement of byte code is necessary, why use Ruby at all? Its seems late in the game to ever implement a standard now.

Comment: I am not sure why you consider the situation in Python in any way different. CPython byte code is for CPython, PyPy byte code is for PyPy, Pyston byte code is for Pyston, and IronPython and Jython don't even *have* a byte code. There *might* be a difference with CPython byte code with regards to guarantees of backwards and forwards compatibility as well as portability between platforms, but other than that, the situation is the same. By the way: if you use YARV, Rubinius, MRuby, MagLev, or Topaz, then your Ruby code is *always* compiled to byte code, without you having to do anything. With …

Comment: I don't consider it different at all, I am not speaking in regards to even having an option to compile to byte-code . It is common and done automatically in Python. When was the last time you saw anyone compiling byte-code in Ruby?

Comment: … IronRuby and JRuby, it may or may not be compiled to byte code, depending on whether the code is "hot" enough. Also, with MagLev, your byte code will be compiled to native code if it is "hot" enough, with Rubinius and YARV, it *might* get compiled to native code depending on the version, and with IronRuby and JRuby, the CIL / JVM byte code might get compiled to native code depending on the CLI VES / JVM implementation.

Comment: @ForeverZer0: I use either Rubinius or YARV, so *every time* I use Ruby.

Comment: That is my ignorance of those ports then.